# Update MySQL table from Dropdown and Form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm posting this question up here because i'm a bit lost. This is my first time working on PHP and MySQL and I'm doing this for my uni assignment. I've managed to do all the CSS, Javascript and part of the PHP/MySQL requirements. The only thing that I have left is:

How do I get the value from my form that is generated through PHP and MYSQLquery and update the respective row of my MySQL table. I've attached an image to make it easier to understand.

[image]

The left side allows a user to search or display all orders. The PHP within will then call itself to update the table on the right. That part I managed to do it. But now part of my assignment requirement is:

```
The Manager should be able to ‘update’ the status of an order from a link
or button next to the order in the table, changing the status from 
(pending | fulfilled | paid | archived). This could be done by returning 
the record to a form in this webpage, to change and ‘confirm’ the change.
```

Now the table generated is actually a form. I've put some snippets of the codes here

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" id=\"regForm\" action=\"https://formtest.php\" name=\"editAll\">\n";
.......
echo "<td>", $row["order_status"],"</td>\n";
echo "<td><select name=\"change_orderstatus[]\" id=\"change_orderstatus[]\">
<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\" >Please Select</option>
<option value=\"pending\">Pending</option>
<option value=\"Fulfilled\">Fulfilled</option>
<option value=\"Paid\">Paid</option>
<option value=\"Archived\">Archived</option>
<option value=\"Delete\">Delete</option>
</select></td>\n";
....
echo "<input type= \"submit\" value=\"Save changes\" id=\"commit\" name=\"editAllquery\" />";
```

If I put `change_orderstatus[]` it supposedly becomes an array but how do I make use of this to update my MySQL Table

I'm attaching another picture to show the bottom where I have the save changes button

[image]

Now I know that Stackoverflow is known for bashing people instead of helping because "all the noobs should learn their stuff and all" (this is from my personal experience) but I'm not asking you to write the codes for me or help me do my assignment.

I'm just asking you to point me to a direction where I can then do it on my own. That's all. I've tried to make my post as clear and as detailed as possible so that I don't get immediately down voted to oblivion.

If you could help me out, that would be great.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to output a form somewhere, I suggest making it like:

```
<form action="phphandler.php" id="form1" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="inp1">
    <input type="hidden" name="status" id="inp2">
</form>
```

Make onChange event for **select** :

```
<select onchange="event.preventDefault(); myFunction(1)" id="sel1">
```

*myFunction(1) should be generated for each select with its unique id using php*

Then function like:

```
function myFunction(id) {
    document.getElementById('inp1').value = id;
    document.getElementById('inp2').value = document.getElementById('sel1').value;
    document.getElementById('form1').submit()
}
```

*All ID's are generated by php except for inp1 and inp2 and form1*

Comment: I haven't really tested if wrote everything correctly, but if you have any question then feel free to ask them.

Comment: It helped me a bit but I ended up extending what you did to make it work. OMG is mySQL hard.

For those who are looking at this question in the future, 
Make use of hidden fields and 

$end = end($_POST);
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 if ($end != $value) {